# Handsontable drag and drop a row or a cell between two handsontables

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

In my scenario I have two handsontables. By default they provide functionality to drag rows in same table.

But I want to drag a row or a cell from one handsontable to another. How can I achieve this...?

Comment: can you plase add some code that you had already developed

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqPxrK

@SamuelJMathew

Comment: Based on my experience, it is difficult to drag from one handsontable to another but you can create a context menu instead of dragging.Dragging and dropping requires some more research.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working. Now I am able to drag from one table to another using Jquery draggable and droppable.